# using System.Net.Sockets; not supported in windows store app architecture, what to use instead?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I created a simple client and server app in windows forms, now I wanted to create it in windows store app framework.  using System.Net.Sockets; isnt supported there . How should I approach to this and what class should i use ? Following is the code in winforms c#: many thanks

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Media;

namespace ChatClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        Socket sck;

        EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

          //what would I use instead in windows store app, using System.Net.Sockets; namespace isnt supported ?
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
        }


        //Getting local IP address through code
        private string GetLocalIP()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            string localIP = "";
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    localIP = ip.ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return localIP;
        }

        private void MessageCallBack (IAsyncResult aResult)
        {
            try
            {

                int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);
                if (size>0)
                {
                    byte[] receivedData = new byte[1464];
                    receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;
                    ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    string receiveMessage = eEncoding.GetString(receivedData);
                    listMessage.Items.Add("Friend : "+receiveMessage);


                }

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }

        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            groupBox1.Text = Environment.UserName;

            textBox1.Text = GetLocalIP().ToString();

            btnSend.Enabled = false;

        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                if (CheckConnection() == 1)
                {
                    btnStart.Text = "Please Wait...";
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.Text));
                    sck.Bind(epLocal);
                    epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(fndIP.Text), Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.Text));
                    sck.Connect(epRemote);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                    sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

                    btnStart.Enabled = false;
                    btnStart.Text = "Connected";

                    btnStart.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
                    btnStart.ForeColor = Color.White;
                    btnSend.Enabled = true;
                    textBox5.Focus();

                    button1.Enabled = true;
                }

                else
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Check Your Internet connection");

                }


            }
            catch(Exception ex1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex1.ToString());

            }

        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] msg = new byte[1500];
                msg = enc.GetBytes(textBox5.Text);
                new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.chat).Play();
                sck.Send(msg);
                listMessage.Items.Add("Me :   "+textBox5.Text);
                new SoundPlayer(Properties.Resources.chat).Play();
                textBox5.Clear();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }


        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private int CheckConnection ()
        {

            Ping myPing = new Ping();
            String host = "74.125.20.147";
            byte[] buffer = new byte[32];
            int timeout = 1000;
            PingOptions pingOptions = new PingOptions();
            PingReply reply = myPing.Send(host, timeout, buffer, pingOptions);
            if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                return 1;
            }


            else
            {

                return 0;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            sck.Close();

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Windows 8 development > How to > How tos (XAML) > Connecting to networks and web services Connecting with sockets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh452976.aspx):

> Send and receive data with TCP or UDP sockets in your Windows Runtime app using features in the `Windows.Networking.Sockets` namespace.

You use UDP, so see [How to connect with a datagram socket (XAML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj635238.aspx) which uses the class [`Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.sockets.datagramsocket.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's in the `Windows.Networking.Sockets` namespace
See [.Net for Windows Store Apps overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230302.aspx#convert) article for a complete description on how to deal with these differences.